# Use OnTouchListener in ImageViews contained in a ListView

Tags: android

I use a ListView that holds Imageviews. The ListView is of course scrollable.
I want to use an OnTouchListener for the Imageviews. The problem is, that the OnTouchListener fires when I actually just want to scroll through the ListView.
How can I solve this Problem?

Here is what the OnTouchListener does:

```
imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

switch(event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

imageView1.setAlpha(0f);
imageView2.setAlpha(1f);


break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

imageView1.setAlpha(1f);
imageView2.setAlpha(0f);

break;
}

 return true;

}

});
```

The ImageViews are one upon the other, so what the code does is it simply turns one picture on and the other off.

Comment: Check out this article,  I think you will find it very helpful: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup

Comment: Can you explain (or provide code) to what your ImageView's OnTouchListener is trying to do?

Comment: I have edited it. Sorry for the bad format.

Comment: Looking at this code,  it seems you want to hide one image in each listview item while scrolling.  Is that correct?

Comment: No I don't want any action while scrolling. I want to either scroll or do what the OnTouchListener should do, and that is to display one picture and hide the other as long as the finger is on the ImageView. So when you put your finger on the ImageView, one picture disappears and the other appears, but only as long as the finger is on it

Answer (score 0):

You might require onItemclicklistener for listview.

Answer (score 0):

In your View.OnTouchListener return `false` instead of `true`.  This will make your listener, not consume the touch event and allow those touches propagate to the parent ListView (the ViewGroup) letting it scroll, while you are able to toggle alphas based on the event being a Down or Up action.

More info here : [View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch(android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent))

I would also recommend reading the input training docs here, https://developer.android.com/guide/input/

Comment: I've already tried it but it doesn't work. 
The event ACTION_DOWN fires once and thats's it. I can scroll after that but nothing else happens.